# Trying to integrate Facebook Authentication into a php web application

Tags: php, facebook

Am trying to integrate facebook authentication into my php web application without using the JavaScript version.

I have downloaded the php sdk.

The basic example works perfectly and i can get the user's public accessible information with the below code.

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
```

However, when i try to request for extended permissions with the below code:

```
$api_call = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos'));   
header("Location: {$api_call}");
```

It keeps loading on facebook with the "Redirecting" in the title bar.

I will very much appreciate if someone can help me out with a link to a tutorial that can help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution.

Passed the response of $facebook->getLoginUrl(); as the href value of the login link. Hope this helps someone else.